# How do I do "SELECT something IN (...)" with jooq?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to do the following with Jooq and can't for the life of me figure out how to do it properly:

```
select name, id in (
  select capability_id 
   from a.capabilities_users 
   where user_id = ?) 
from a.capabilities;
```

Basically I want to get all items (capabilities) and know whether each one applies to a particular user.  It seems that all the condition type operators (like greater than or in) can only be used in the where and not the select.  And I can't think of how else to express this.

Worst case, I can do a select count and then do the boolean logic in Java, but I was hoping to use fetchMap.

Comment: What database are you using jOOQ with? Most databases don't allow predicates in the projection, so I suspect this might be PostgreSQL?

Comment: @LukasEder: that syntax would be invalid in Postgres as well. I think the SQL is meant as an example, it's definitely not valid SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Works with PostgreSQL. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1651. In fact, from [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) integration test experience, I can say that it'll work with Derby, H2, HSQLDB, MariaDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have never found a very authoritative documentation for this rather surprising behaviour, but to PostgreSQL, a `condition` is just any `value expression` or `expression` that evaluates to a `boolean` type: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html. I.e. *"[...] where condition is any expression that evaluates to a result of type boolean"*. Obviously, this liberal understanding of "expression" makes PostgreSQL's SQL dialect even more powerful, as you can put predicates everywhere, e.g. in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I just had to blog about this awesome SQL dialect feature: http://blog.jooq.org/2013/09/14/why-postgresql-is-so-awesome

Comment: @LukasEder: I stand corrected ;) Thanks for the examples, one really never stops learning...

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea I was doing anything exotic. Interesting blog post.  :-)

I'm using PostgreSQL btw.  Love it.  Also really love jOOQ!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Actually, the SQL:2008 standard defines `6.34 <boolean value expression>` precisely like this. `<boolean primary> ::= <predicate> | <boolean predicand>`. Which makes PostgreSQL an even more awesome database!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your database and schema meta data, a `LEFT JOIN` might be a better choice than a predicate in the projection. You should of course verify this in the execution plan.

#### Solving this with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
-- NVL2 is Oracle syntax. 
-- jOOQ will emulate NVL2 using CASE, if it's not available in your database
SELECT c.name, NVL2(cu.capability_id, 1, 0)
FROM a.capabilities c
LEFT OUTER JOIN a.capabilities_users cu
  ON (c.id = cu.capability_id
  AND cu.user_id = ?)
```

The above assumes, of course, that there is a unqiue constraint on `cu(user_id, capability_id)`. This would then translate into jOOQ as such:

```java
Capabilities c = CAPABILITIES.as("c");
CapabilitiesUsers cu = CAPABILITIES_USERS.as("cu");

Field<String> key = c.NAME.as("key");
Field<Boolean> value = nvl2(
  CAPABILITIES_USER.CAPABILITY_ID, true, false
).as("value");

Map<String, Boolean> map =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(key, value)
   .from(c)
   .leftOuterJoin(cu)
   .on(c.ID.eq(cu.CAPABILITY_ID))
   .and(cu.USER_ID.eq(...))
   .fetchMap(key, value);
```

#### Solving this with a predicate in the projection:

If you really prefer a predicate in the projection, you might try [`DSL.field(Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field%28org.jooq.Condition%29), which allows for precisely this:

```
Field<String> key = CAPABILITIES.NAME.as("key");
Field<Boolean> value = field(
  CAPABILITIES.ID.in(
    select(CAPABILITY_ID)
   .from(CAPABILITIES_USERS)
   .where(CAPABILITIES_USERS.USER_ID.eq(...))
  )
).as("value");

Map<String, Boolean> map =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(key, value)
   .from(CAPABILITIES)
   .fetchMap(key, value);
```

Note that if you're using a standards-compliant database, which doesn't allow for predicates to be treated as columns, [`DSL.field(Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field%28org.jooq.Condition%29) will render an equivalent `CASE` statement for you.

Comment: It seems to me a good query optimizer ought to be able to rewrite that predicate-in-select query as a join. Postgresql is normally pretty good at query rewriting, but I would run an EXPLAIN on it before assuming it did that.

Comment: @EricS: You're probably right with PostgreSQL being good with this. Specifically, if both `c.ID` and `cu.UER_ID` have `NOT NULL` constraints in addition to indexes, a merge join might be extremely quick.